# best way to implement an Android Application exchanging constant stream of data with a Computer over a TCP Server

Tags: android, multithreading, tcp

I'm developing an app that will take in and display telemetric data in real time and i want to know what is the best way to implement the exchange over a TCPServer?
Should i use multithreading to open and close the sockets with every new piece of data or have the connection remain open until the program is terminated?

Comment: Why would you need multithreading to open and close a tcp connection? Or am I missing something? Please provide more information.

Comment: @Tudor - you don't.  All you need to open and close sockets continually is a really poor design.

Comment: well then im out of ideas ive searched extensively for code or tricks that will allow me to transmit a continuous stream of data unless its just as simple as opening a socket and reading from it which i have done in my Com -> Com code i can get the data stream to transmit perfectly but when i port the exact same code to android in order to implement a Com -> Droid communication it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you continually open and close sockets over a high-latency radio link, your performance will be very poor.  The only, (lame), excuse for opening and closing TCP sockets in this kind of app is that it provides a sort of 'message protocol'.  Unfortunately, it is often used for exactly that purpose :((